# How to restart the job again without freeing pipeline input

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, omnithreadlibrary

I'm using OTL, pipelines tasks to check a bunch of URLs. My question is: How to restart the search again quickly, I mean it takes time to add the strings again to Pipeline input and start again, is there a way to do that? If not? Am I using the wrong OTL pattern? my app is just a simple checker with 1 pipeline stage.
Thank You.

```
type
...
Private
   FInProcess: Boolean;
   procedure SetInProcess(const Value: Boolean);
   property inProcess: Boolean read FInProcess write SetInProcess;

...
var U,zz :  string;
  begin
   if Value = InProcess then exit;

    FInProcess := Value;

    if Value then
     Timer1.Enabled := Value;

    If not Value then
      FlushData; //take pipeline output to Form1

    If not Value then
      pipeline := nil;

       If not Value then
       begin                                // this how i restart checking
        if CheckBox3.Checked = True then
          begin
             LChecker := TstringList.Create;
             zz := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'Checker.txt';
             LChecker.LoadFromFile(zz);
             pipeline := Parallel.Pipeline;
             pipeline.Stage(Retriever).NumTasks(60).Run;

            try
              for U in LChecker do
                pipeline.Input.Add(U);
              pipeline.Input.CompleteAdding;
            finally
              LChecker.Free;
              end;
             inProcess := True;
          end else

       ShowMessage('Checking Complete');
       end;


 procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 begin
   pipeline := Parallel.Pipeline;
   pipeline.Stage(Retriever).NumTasks(60).Run;
    try
      for U in LChecker do //chars : StringList
        pipeline.Input.Add(U);
      pipeline.Input.CompleteAdding;
    finally
      LChecker.Free;
      end;
    inProcess := True;

end;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but keep in mind this: Once a pipeline input is 'completed' (i.e., CompleteAdding has been called on it), it cannot be reverted to a working state. IOW, after you call CompleteAdding the only option is to recreate the pipeline from scratch.

Comment: @Gabr assuming the input collection would not be sealed and just be let exist emptied, would OTL then free pipeline worker threads or reuse them, for other OTL tasks, or would they be kept in paused/suspended state consuming resources? In other words, would be keeping stalled emptied (but not finalized) pipelines a noticeable resource drain or neglectible ?

Comment: Stalled pipeline blocks one thread, but default parallel pool does not set an upper limit to number of concurrently executing threads so new ones can always be started.

Comment: So - nothing would be blocked, the code would just use some threads, all in a suspended state (WaitForObject).

Comment: well, i've removed `CompleteAdding` and just left `pipeline := Parallel.Pipeline;
             pipeline.Stage(Retriever).NumTasks(60).Run;` to reaster the check, and it's working well for now @gabr